# How to rotate image with location or other

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

Imagine a UIView with a UIImageView in the middle, and when I rotate the iphone the image still looks up, it means that when I rotate the iphone to the right the UIImageView rotate to the left in the same degrees. I had seen some apps like iAngle Meter that use this option so how can I do this?

Pd. I only know how to rotate the image, I use:

```
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288 //pi
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) (angle / 180.0 * M_PI)

- (void)rotateImage: (UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration curve:(int)curve degrees:(CGFloat)degrees {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees));
image.transform = transform;

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Application line:

```
[self rotateImage:logoAnim duration:0.5 curve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn degrees:-30];
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Look into the UIViewController's method:

```
     -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
                                             duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

     }
```

It will inform you when it will begin the rotation to orientation that you have enabled to your application via info.plist and in -shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation: method.